# magento 2 Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\Registry

Tags: magento2, admin, customer-account

i am getting this error while compiling,when i add dependency injection then getting other error like,filefactory if this solved then getting customerfactory.
Actually i want to do custom code in my controller when user click - 
[image]

```
     <?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Sendcredentials;
        use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

    class Index extends  \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
    {
        /**
         * Customer compare grid
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout
         */
       public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            array $data = [] 
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);

        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $resultLayout = $this->_resultLayoutFactory->create();
            $getBlock = $resultLayout->getLayout()->createBlock("Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sendcredentials");
            echo $getBlock->getCustomCustomerId();

            die;  

        }
    }
```

Actually i need customer id in my custom controller.

Comment: i edit question please check

Comment: customer is already created,i just need to write my code in my controller file,when click on "send credentials" please refer image above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't extend properly  `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index`  to your class when try to call  `__construct` . If you check the code of then you find a lot of parameters need  `__construct:\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index`.

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Sendcredentials;

class Index  extends \ Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
{

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry, 
            \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $formFactory, 
            \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $viewHelper, 
            \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $random, 
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Mapper $customerMapper,
            \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
            \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $objectFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory) 
            {
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry, $fileFactory, $customerFactory, $addressFactory, $formFactory, $subscriberFactory, $viewHelper, $random, $customerRepository, $extensibleDataObjectConverter, $addressMapper, $customerAccountManagement, $addressRepository, $customerDataFactory, $addressDataFactory, $customerMapper, $dataObjectProcessor, $dataObjectHelper, $objectFactory, $layoutFactory, $resultLayoutFactory, $resultPageFactory, $resultForwardFactory, $resultJsonFactory);
    }

    public function execute() {

    }

}
```

No of parameters at  `__construct:\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index` is 25 ,https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index.php#L201-L225

but your extends class's  has two  parameters `parent::__construct($context, $data)` .So no of parameters should be same for extends __construct and original  one.

Comment: but how to get customer id here ?

Comment: `$this->initCurrentCustomer(); `  provide you  customer id

Comment: yes i already try this after your code but it show 0

Comment: What is the URL of  button  sendCrendtial?

Comment: localhost/projectname/admin/xxx/sendcredentials/index/customer_id/1/

Comment: public function execute()
    {
        echo $this->initCurrentCustomer();
        die;  
    }

it print 0(zero)

Comment: You have to change little lit on your url params `admin/xxx/sendcredentials/index/customer_id/1` to `admin/xxx/sendcredentials/index/id/1` .parameters name will be `id` instead of `customer_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the constructor method from your class.
the original class `Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index` has a constructor with way more parameters than you provided in your code.

Comment: ok i will remove constructor class.
but how may i get customer id here ?

Comment: I am not able to get customer id

Comment: you can send the id via GET from the button. How did you add the button in the page?

Comment: thank you so much for your reply Upvote